# Removing malware warning from website

Tags: domains, wordpress, malware

Our site had this warning **The Site ahead contains Malware Warning**. We created brand new site on different server on a completely different hosting and the pointed the domain to the new server.

Nothing from previous server was moved to new hosting. Its more than 6 weeks now. Warning is still there.  We also contacted our domain registrar, they replied : **Its not their fault and they can't really help us.**

We've tried all the instruction that we found on internet.

[image: Warning on the site]

Comment: Make sure it is not on any of the numerous blacklists. You can check https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to see. The question is its- Is this warning browser based? In otherwords, it is not coming from the Google search engine. It is something the browser is doing. If so, then it may help to know what browsers do this.

Comment: If your sits is using WordPress is may have become infected again through a common plug-in.

Comment: We've scanned the whole site with available security plugins like **WP-Security** and **Anti-Malware** from **GOTMLS.NET**. Both reported no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem before.
Some hacker add backdoor or spam script or autospam, autoemail software on your website or server. 
Make a clean re-install for your server. and maker a clean re-upload your website.
When all done, install a anti-virus software for server if possible.

Comment: We actually fully left the old server. New site is on completely new server. 

Not a single bit of old server was moved to new server.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, these are the steps for removing this.

1. Download your entire page with database on local computer
2. Use some localserver, XAMPP or WAMP or whatever and run your page there
3. Scan the site with some antivirus program and delete all malicious code.
4. If some part of site fells apart (or if you using CMS like wordpress, joomla or similar) make sure to replace it with updated version
5. Update everything to latest version and put online
6. Eternal life.

Comment: We've scanned the whole site with available security plugins like **WP-Security** and **Anti-Malware** from **GOTMLS.NET**. Both reported no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the Chrome browser warning. If you have not created a webmaster tools account, do so now.

Once created, go to the search console (after adding the site to your account and verify ownership) by uploading a file given by Google to your sites root folder. Also, add a sitemap, if possible and submit the site to index.

Once that is done, apply for a "Reconsideration Request". It can take up to a week but that is much faster than just hoping it goes away.

Step by step instructions can be found on Googles site at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35843?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I also got similar warning when visiting one of the page on my site. I have troubleshooted the problem and found the reason - the product I promoted somehow as identified as a malicious program. I didn't know how it happened. Finally, I deleted the page and the problem was solved. So, do you promote any potentially dangerous program on your website? If not, your website might be attacked by some malware. Try run a malware scanner to detect and remove it.